# Failed to Resolve com.android.support?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to create new project and run on simulator. But, it is not allowing the mobile frames as well as giving the following error message.

[image]

Do help!
[image]

Below is my SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

just Change version in build.gradle(app) by whatever version you have.
if you forgot your installed version then see in SDK manager and expand it.

change like:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
```

if it doesn't work then try "27+", whatever version you have installed.

Comment: see this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddyyR.png and click on "show package details"